# Is great sage never tried to follow brahmachari ? yes/No

Tags: brahmacharya

source : http://www.vedantauk.com/Magazine/2010/Jul-Aug2010.pdf

From this  i got thought in my mind ,my thought is given below

Is  the statement is true/false ?

Great sage  never tried to follow brahmachari they just loved the God deeply and brahmachari qualities  automatically came in their soul

suppose if this statement is true then

My confusion is that lord Buddha  never beleive in God and he never loved the god deeply , then How he have attained nirvana ?

Comment: Search for the truth is same as the search for God, because God is the truth and its truth alone which is packaged as God or master to the world.Temporary comes out of eternal but not vice-versa, which is same as saying Maya coming out of God. Buddha seeked truth because he himself was manifestation of intellect or cosmic Buddhi, but do you expect every being on earth to be born extremely intellectual, they could either be strong in strength, arts, architecture etc., five fingers in a hand are never equal, hence the need for depiction of an unknown controller called God for the world.

Comment: good word @ manu kumar that mean  truth have many way to reached

Comment: Everything is made out of truth, its not like a person who attains Nirvana or Moksha is successful and rest in the world are failure, the goal is personal choiced evolution just like a child grows into a mature person. Not every one can be forced into Moksha nor everyone can be forced to live in the society, its the free will of every being. If everyone attains truth, earth will become empty and perish, if everyone is lost in Maya, heavens will go empty, so balance is the key.

Comment: good point and logics @ManuKumar

Comment: Is the statement is true/false ?   -- Which statement are you talking about? Can you post the statement in the question itself by copy-pasting from the PDF? @jasmine

Comment: This thought came in my mind .....im talking about this statement Great sage never tried to follow brahmachari they just loved the God deeply and brahmachari qualities automatically came in their soul  @Rickross..........see page no ; 160.....of the given pdf

Comment: There are only 52 pages in that PDF... So can you tell which page I need to check? page 160 is not there @jasmine

Comment: ya  ,,,@Rickross but page no : mention there .......as page no ; is not from1

Comment: Oh now I understood what you are talking about. Yes there is a page no 160 in that PDF @jasmine

Comment: "Great sage never tried to follow brahmachari they just loved the God deeply and brahmachari qualities automatically came in their soul" -- i couldn't find this exact statement on page 18 of pdf or 160 of the content..